# Multiply shortcode value by jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have a shortcode on my website like this:

```
<figcaption class="caption">[id=123]</figcaption>
```

This will output 8.

I want this to be multiplied by *5, so the output will be 40.

How can I achieve this with JavaScript?

Comment: you can use mutationObserver to detect this replacement and replace the number with x5 number then. But it seems the task is easier then I think, maybe you should give more information

Comment: @crystalbit Thank you for the information. Im very new to this and I just want to start from the front-end. So I really don't know what mutationObserver is.

Comment: it can be too complex for this task. better you need to understand what changes the scortcode to the number and then do additional settings there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shortcode is like this:

```
<figcaption class="caption">[id=123]</figcaption>
```

and the HTML rendered from the shortcode is like this:

```
<figcaption class="caption">8</figcaption>
```

then you just treat it as simple HTML content:

```js
const captions = document.querySelectorAll('.caption')

captions.forEach(e => {
  const value = !isNaN(e.textContent) ? Number(e.textContent) * 5 : 'Not a number'
  e.textContent = value
})
```

```css
.caption {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<figcaption class="caption">8</figcaption>
```